# Drupal 8 passing current nid to block template

Tags: symfony, drupal, drupal-8

I have created a custom module that uses a custom block to display a list of nodes (I can't use D8 views in this particular case).
Inside the block twig template I need to filter this list on the current `nid` (node id of the current page) and I'm passing the value to twig in this way:

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
$nid = $node->nid->value;
return array(
        'currentnid' => $nid,
    );
```

Everything is working fine, but changing page the `nid` passed to the block template is still the same. I think this is related to template caching: by clearing the cache and reloading the page I get the correct value for the current page, but moving to another page I'm still getting the same `nid`!
Is there something I can do to prevent `nid` value to be cached?
I think that the best solution would be to get the current `nid` value directly inside the template, but I'm inside the custom block and I don't know how to get it. Any idea? I have already checked the `kint()` output and the current page `nid` is not present at the block template level.

Comment: Maybe you should ask on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot @malcolm I didn't know that site, I'll try for sure.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
namespace Drupal;
$node_v1 = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
$node_v2 = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')

?>
```

Comment: you can get using this

Answer (score 1):

in your build array try using cache tags with your current nid

```
return array(
    'currentnid' => $nid,
    '#cache' => [
        'tags' => ['node:'.$nid],
    ],
);
```